# setImageViewBitmap not working in android widget

Tags: android, bitmap, widget, rgb

When I try to put a bitmap on a widget I used this :

```
theBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(WW, HH,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
.
.
// draw something using a canvas
.
.
rviews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.time,theBitmap);
```

This works on my phone but not on my Galaxy tablet or Galaxy Note,

if I copy **theBitmap** into a new **ARGB_4444** then it works on all devices:

```
Bitmap clone= theBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444, false); // workaround
rviews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.time, clone);
```

Comment: Might this be the same as: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8489 ?

Comment: yes, I saw this before, but I need ARGB_8888 because of quality and transparency.

Comment: You'll likely need to send less data, which means a smaller or downsampled image, or pass the URI to the image instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, without your workaround, check your logcat output for:

```
ERROR/JavaBinder(20204): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

You're probably hitting the file size limit for the IPC transaction that holds your changes to the `RemoteViews` hierarchy.

When you copy the bitmap with the `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444` config, each pixel will be represented with 2 bytes, whereas `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` (the default config on 2.3 and up) each pixel is 4 bytes [[Source]](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html).

By using your workaround, you're passing half as much data, and thus, squeaking by the size limit. [This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/KKEyW6XdDvg/wgetULOJq3QJ) suggests the size limit is 1MB, but I'm not sure if that varies per OS version or manufacturer.

**Update:** A different approach to passing an image would be to not send the bitmap itself, but rather pass a URI to the file on disk. Then, you need to make sure that other processes will have read access to your file (the launcher will run in a different process for example). If you're writing out files into your `/data/data/my.package.name/` directory, you can do this by specifying [MODE_WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) on [Context.openFileOutput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). For example:

```
remoteViews.setUri(R.id.time, "setImageURI", Uri.fromFile(file));
```

Comment: setUri really helped me out.  Great advice...thank you!